# Importing semicolon separated .txt file in Python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, import-from-csv

I am trying to **import a semicolon separated huge .txt file** in Python using pandas. The file does not having a fixed Column length. This is not allowing me to import the data correctly. I tried the below approach but seems like this is not working as well. Can someone suggest an easy alternate way to get over it?

```
#import libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Loading the .txt file
#dataset = pd.read_table('a.txt' , sep = ';' , header=None)

df = pd.DataFrame()

with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        df = pd.concat( [df, pd.DataFrame([tuple(line.strip().split(';'))])], ignore_index=True )
```

Comment: Where's the Data?

Comment: Semicolon-separated text file sounds like a job for csv reader. Have you tried it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data?

Comment: Please find the example data : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IvgqWTsGcUi8oEniAd1V90uYiPeEVrSQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the problem that happens if you try your commented-out version using `read_table`?

Comment: The data does not gets separated by ; evenly and throws the error : CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 9, saw 6

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?  It doesn't make sense to load data into a DataFrame if it doesn't have a tabular structure with the same number of columns in each row.

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you. Without an example of the data it is impossible to test...

```
#import libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Loading the .txt file
df = pd.read_csv('a.txt' , sep=';' , header=None)
```

Comment: Please find the example data : drive.google.com/file/d/1IvgqWTsGcUi8oEniAd1V90uYiPeEVrSQ/…

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not tabular and is not suited for a pandas DataFrame.  For instance, the first two lines are:

```
Breakfast & Brunch;American (Traditional);Restaurants
Sandwiches;Restaurants
```

One of these has three fields and the other has two.  pandas DataFrames are designed for *tabular* data in which every row has the same number of columns, and every column has the same number of rows.

Comment: Thanks. If not Pandas can you please suggest how do I get this data loaded in tabular format? I need to run Apriori algorithm on this data set to mine the frequent pattern in the full data set.